# Django model field custom validator returned value not saved

Tags: django, django-models, django-validation, django-model-field

I have the following implementation for the phone number custom validation. It does the validation correctly, but the returned value (formatted) is not saved in the model instance. I don't use a custom form and data is entered from admin panel.

## custom validator

```
def phone_number_validator(value):
    if value:
        value = value.strip()
        value = value.replace(' ', '')

        digits = []
        non_digits = []
        for c in value:
            if c.isdigit():
                digits.append(c)
            else:
                non_digits.append(c)

        if len(non_digits):
            raise ValidationError('Only numbers and spaces are allowed for this field.')
        elif len(digits) < 10 or len(digits) > 10:
            raise ValidationError('Phone number should be exactly 10 digits.')
        elif (not value.startswith('07')) and (not value.startswith('0')):
            raise ValidationError('Invalid phone number.')

        if value.startswith('07'):  # mobile number
            value = f'{value[0:3]} {value[3:6]} {value[6:]}'
        elif value.startswith('0'):  # landline
            value = f'{value[0:3]} {value[3:4]} {value[4:7]} {value[7:]}'
        print(value) #### here the correct format is displayed
        return value
```

## models.py

```
hotline = models.CharField(max_length=PHONE_NUMBER_LENGTH, validators=[phone_number_validator])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of a validator is only to check the value against a set of criteria. It is not meant to modify value.

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/validators/

Answer (score 0):

This was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43811083/2837411) (and from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/validation/#using-validators)).

If you want to use a `validate_or_process`-function, i have an approach in my own [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71046355/validating-and-processing-djangoadminform-filefield)